# Does stripe customer portal support Subscription Schedule?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripes

I am using stripe customer portal and i want downgrading a subscription to not be Immediate i want it to happen at the end of the current subscription and i know to do that you need Subscription Schedule, so can i do it with stripe customer portal ?

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't currently possible with Stripe's Customer Portal. The closest behavior you could achieve with the portal is to disable prorations so that the downgrade happens immediately, but you aren't charged for any change in price. When the subscription next renews, you'll start paying for the downgraded price. You can disable prorations for the portal two different ways:

- In the **Dashboard** you'd check your [portal settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/billing/portal) and make sure "Prorate subscription updates" is not enabled
- In the **API** you'd create a new Portal Configuration and make sure `features.subscription_update.proration_behavior: none`  (see [api ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create#create_portal_configuration-features-subscription_update-proration_behavior))

Comment: Hi bro thanks for the answer.
removing prorations doesn't solve it because no matter what in my case downgrade shouldn't happen immediately it should happen after the current subscription ends.